# UIView's height which is in Interface Builder differed in simulator

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I am using xcode 4.5 with ios 6 in mountain lion.Whenever I add any objects like UIview,UIImageview etc in interface builder,object's height or width or the order i have added is changed in simulator.I tried freedom Metrics also.
    How can I bring the same width and height I see in interface builder to simulator?any help please?

Comment: I assume, you've set "autosizing" to "none", didn't you?

Comment: I am running into the same exact problem and provided more detailed information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13724173/incorrect-uiview-bounds-drawing-in-the-simulator)

Answer (score 1):

Click the "Apply Retina 4 Form Factor" button in the display layout. You have this set for Retina 4 so the screen is resizing for 3.5 when running in the simulator. You can verify this by running the iPhone5 simulator (Retina 4 inch).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Matthias is probably right, in the interface builder window on the rightmost panel there will be autosizing and resizing options. Play with them and remove any vertical resizing; it should fix your problem.

Comment: I have set correctly autosizing.But still I am facing same problem.